# Highlight a word in a silverlight textblock

Tags: silverlight, textbox, highlight, textblock

I need a way to highlight a text in a silverlight textblock or textbox. This is for highlighting search results like if you try to Ctrl+F in your browser and search for a word, the browser will highlight the matched words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a textblock you can use a `Run` to highlight words, for example:-

```
  <TextBlock>Ordinary Text&#160;<Run Foreground="Red">Highlighted Text</Run>&#160;More Ordinary Text</TextBlock>
```

Note the use of the Xml character entity `&#160` which is the non-breaking space, which is necessary because Xaml parsing (as result of its reliance on XML parsing) means the white space directly before a `<` and white space directly after a `>` is ignored.

Comment: Hi Anthony, thanks for the reply but what I need is for it to highlight the background not changing the foreground text.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem and found this question in Silverlight forum. Maybe it could help you.

[How to Highlight a particular WRONG word in Textbox to make SpellCheck feature](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/211450/498767.aspx)

This is how I would implement the search function:

```
private void Find(RichTextBox richTextBox, string term)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    var inlines = richTextBox.Blocks
        .OfType<Paragraph>()
        .SelectMany(paragraph => paragraph.Inlines);

    foreach( var inline in inlines )
    {
        builder.Append(((Run)inline).Text);
    }

    var regex = new Regex(term);
    var matchedStrings = regex.Matches(builder.ToString());
    foreach( var item in matchedStrings )
    {
        // Whatever you want to do.
    }
}
```

Comment: What i need to implement here is search functionality. That's why i need to highlight the background.